# Is it possible to create a floating widget with React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I have seen a lot of mobile apps that come with a floating widget to do certain tasks such as recording the screen when you exit the app.

I haven't seen a way to implement this in react-native yet. Is it possible?

*I am not talking about a floating action button here.*

Comment: I think you can do it but not in react native part but in native android part. Then you can write bridge to use that component

Comment: Use this https://github.com/hybriteq/react-native-floating-bubble